# Compare Google Analytics date ranges

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, date-range

I am working on a redesign and we would like to validate this by comparing the old design's data to the new design's data. The new design will be used from april 2018. From that moment will we start collecting data through Google Analytics to see if we improved. 
What I find difficult is to which date range should I compare this data. Should I compare it to April 2017 (one year ago) or March 2018 (one month ago) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit easy to answer as you can compare your data with last month March 2018, Also you can wait till 3 months and set the comparison with last 3 months to see any improvement. No need to compare with April 2017 as there might be so many up and down between year.